# Canonical question on enabling shell-escape in different editors

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, big-list

#### Update

I added the question: [How to enable shell-escape?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598818/how-to-enable-shell-escape/598824). **Please contribute with an answer for your own editor or toolchain.** Thank you.

---

There are many questions where (part of) the solution is to compile with shell-escape enabled. The OP does not always know how to enable this flag. This can usually be resolved by providing a link to an earlier question about the specific procedure for the editor of the OP.

There are a few such questions, like [How to enable shell-escape in TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82699/how-to-enable-shell-escape-in-texworks), [How can I enable write 18 on a MikTeX installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37489/how-can-i-enable-write-18-on-a-miktex-installation?noredirect=1&lq=1) (answers for WinEdt and TeXworks), [How to invoke latex with the -shell-escape flag in TeXStudio (former TeXMakerX)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/how-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texstudio-former-texmakerx), [How to have latexmk always use -shell-escape?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374160/how-to-have-latexmk-always-use-shell-escape).

Would it be a good idea to make one canonical question about this to collect information about multiple editors in one place? It would have the same "one answer per editor" structure as the canonical [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides), and be fully Community Wiki.

This would have the following advantages:

- Easier to link, no need to find the correct post for the editor/compilation procedure of the OP
- More general, so no need to find out which editor the OP uses in a lengthy and regularly unsuccessful comment exchange
- Not cluttered by question details unrelated to shell escape as such, as in some of the currently existing questions
- Easy way for regulars to contribute to this question with the settings for their favorite editor or tool(chain)
- More likely to be updated when a GUI of an editor or tool configuration procedure changes

Some disadvantages:

- Takes work to write and keep up to date
- Possibly difficult for a new user to find their editor in a large question

Any thoughts? I can write the question and answers for some tools I am familiar with: Linux terminal, Windows command prompt, Latexmk, Arara, Overleaf. I don't have (current) experience with any special-purpose LaTeX editor, so that would need to be contributed by other people.

Comment: Nicely done, that's a really helpful resource :)